# Is "al ganar" really grammatical?

Tags: gramática

I ran across this sentence in [a news article](http://politicaparami.com/2018/03/11/cual-es-el-plan-de-beto-orourke-para-ganar-el-voto-de-los-inmigrantes/):

> O’Rourke y Cruz aseguraron sus nominaciones **al ganar** las elecciones primarias de sus respectivos partidos.

I see that they used *"al ganar"*. Is this a typo or is there really a grammatical feature that allows the placement of a definite article before a verb? If such a feature exists, I'd like to know how it works, preferably with a pointer to an external source to back up the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definite article *el* can be placed in front of a verb when it is being used as a noun.  For example, I can say just as well *comer con los amigos es divertido* as I can *el comer con los amigos es divertido*, although it's generally more common to just use the infinitive.

That said, *al [infinitive]* is a special construction, meaning *upon*.  Thus in the sentence you provided, we can read it as

> O'Rourke and Cruz secured their nominations ***upon*** winning the primary elections…

Comment: A more common translation would be **by winning**.

Comment: @CarlosArturoSerrano that is certainly the more idiomatic rendering, but the OP is curious about *al inf.* generally, and since both Spanish and English distinguish temporal *al/upon* from causative *por/by*, I kept it with the temporal wording

Comment: Thanks. I had been under the mistaken impression that verbs could only be used as nouns in past participle form. You didn't provide a link, but a search for "al infinitive" points me to articles like https://www.thoughtco.com/using-al-followed-by-an-infinitive-3079461 that confirm your explanation.